# AWS Regional failover with secondary Region having no resources running untill failover happens

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an application running in N.Virginia Region. I want to configure Regional failover such that if my N.Virgina region or application goes down, same application should come up secondary Region. Initially secondary Region should not have any resources. May be we can only have a CloudFormation template for application or an Lambda function in secondary Region which could bring up all the resources in secondary Region.

For data replication between regions, I will have snapshots of EBS copied periodically to secondary region, and will run a Read replica of RDS in secondary region. But I want, EC2, Loadbalancer, EBS and other resources to spin up on failover.

My primary concern is to achieve Region level high availability without having to spend cost on secondary Region until failover happens.

Comment: You will always have some resource cost in fail over region. All application data must be backed up to the fail over region, always and continuously per your RPO recovery point objective.  "Initially secondary Region should not have any resources" is not feasible, if you want region level fail over.

Comment: I will have snapshots of EBS copied periodically to secondary region, and will run a Read replica of RDS in secondary region. But I want, EC2, Loadbalancer, EBS and other resources to spin up on failover.